# ASP SqlDataSource UPDATE - AJAX for partial page post back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am handling a `div` click event with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)- on `div` click, call [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) button by `ID`.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', (function(clickEvent) {
  document.getElementById("Button1").click();
}))
```

Here is the `ASP` button markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="my_ClickEvent" Text="Button" CssClass="hide" />
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void my_ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "Some Name";
  SqlDataSource1.Update();
  Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Here is the `div` markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
  <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="200000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="True" />
  <div class="square" id="myDiv" runat="server">
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <p id="ImUnavailable">Unavailable for Dispatch</p>
        <div class="table">
          <div class="table-cell">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
              <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
              </Triggers>
              <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="Grid" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="PhysicalAddress">
                  <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="OwnerName" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName">
                      <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                      <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Building" HeaderText="Building" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Building" ItemStyle-CssClass="building">
                      <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                      <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeOn" HeaderText="TimeOn" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="TimeOn">
                      <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                      <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IPAddress" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="IPAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                      <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                      <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhysicalAddress" HeaderText="PhysicalAddress" ShowHeader="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PhysicalAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                      <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Available" HeaderText="Available" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Available" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                      <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                  </Fields>
                  <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:DetailsView>
              </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I have the `DetailsView` wrapped in an [updatepanel](/questions/tagged/updatepanel), which updates on a `Timer` interval trigger. When the timer reaches it's interval, the [updatepanel](/questions/tagged/updatepanel)will post back to the database and the `DetailsView` is kept up to date. This happens in the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)[updatepanel](/questions/tagged/updatepanel), so the page itself is not refreshed.

I am unsure how to achieve this with my `div` click. I am trying to click the `div`, call the `ASP` button, update the `SqlDataSource`, all without refreshing the entire page. The `div` click event works now, but it is not using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). I am becoming a bit confused when researching solutions for this like I am missing something simple.

Any advice appreciated. Thank you!

***EDIT***

So, I created a separate `UpdatePanel` and structured it like so... it still refreshes the whole page when I click `Button1`...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ...
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="my_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="you_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

All I am trying to do is update a column in a SQL table when I click Button1. It works, but refreshes the page.

Thanks again

Comment: Put your `asp:button` inside `updatepanel` or add `trigger` to updatepanel`.

Comment: I placed the button inside the UpdatePanel, set ChildrenAsTriggers = "true" on the update panel, and it still refreshes the whole page. I also tried adding an asyncpostbacktrigger for the click event, still refreshes the whole page...

Comment: Try to use `LinkButton` instead of `Button`

Comment: Ok. For what purpose? Just curious. The button works, is there a difference in `LinkButton` or `Button` when it comes to AJAX?

Comment: Any visibility on this? I have everything working properly on the site apart from the div clicks refreshing the page. The div click calls an asp button which updates a SqlDataSource column. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my event output posted above and answered my own question.

I changed my code-behind to:

```
protected void my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "My Name";SqlDataSource1.Update();}
```

...and of course I am no longer called the Response.Redirect. It is working as expected now.

Thank you!